# Program to monitor file usage and access

Tags: windows, monitoring

Can you recommend me a program on Windows that can:

1. List all the files accessed by a running application
2. List all the applications accessing a given file

A GUI would be nice but not compulsory, and I need a freeware software, or one with free options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProcessMonitor from Microsoft (used to be Sysinternal) can record real-time access to files (and more)

https://docs.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

This is useful if you want to record which files an application has accessed over time, e.g. during startup.

ProcessExplorer (a task manager replacement) can show the *currently* open files for an application

https://docs.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Using the "Find handle" option it's possible to find the applications accessing a specific file.